# Java comments shortcut is weird in Eclipse Jee 2019 03

Tags: java, spring, comments, shortcut

I'm using Eclipse JEE 2019-03.

I used the comments shortcut in Java using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

I want to it works like '*img1*' but it works like '*img2*'.

Should I change Eclipse tools?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: You shouldn't, second version is more readable and you can clearly see it's a comment when you have a large block. It isn't a question for SO tho.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + F?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest you to always use that kind of format. This format of comment is done for documentation purpose only as far as I know. So unless you want to make a doc for your program, its best to avoid such convention. But you can still do it in Eclipse:

`Alt` + `Shift` +  `J` 
Add Javadoc Comment Add a Javadoc comment to the active field/method/class

Source: https://dzone.com/articles/add-comments-and-javadocs